# Type casting & Type conversion

Tags: type-conversion

Could anyone give me a definition of Type Casting and why and when should we use it?

I tried looking for material online, but couldn't find anything that would explain me why exactly we need type casting and when to use it.

An example would be great!

Comment: Which language are we discussing?

Comment: -0. broad, and something you can type in on google. I don't feel like losing points for downvoting this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you only lose points down-voting answers, not questions..

Comment: @larsmans Type Conversion as a topic in Computing, You can provide example in C#

Comment: "When we should use it" depends rather on the language. C programs tend to be full of casts, which C++ programs can avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type casting is the mechanism of forcing an object into a particular type. In layman's terms it is picking up a letter (the abstract) from the mailbox and forcing it into a bill (the specific, the concrete).

This is typically relevant in software development because we deal with a lot of abstraction so there are times when we'll inspect a property of a given object and not immediately know the real concrete type of the said object.

In C# for example I might be interested in examining the contents of a datasource linked to a particular control.

```
object data = comboBox.DataSource;
```

The .DataSource property is of type "object" (which in C# is as abstract as you can get), this is because the DataSource property supports a range of different concrete types and wants to allow the programmer to choose from a wide range of types to use.

So, returning to my examination. With this object type, there isn't a great deal I can do with "object data".

```
data.GetType();     // tells me what type it actually is
data.ToString();    // typically just outputs the name of the type in string form, might be overridden though
data.GetHashCode(); // this is just something that gets used when the object is put in a hashtable
data.Equals(x);      // asks if the object is the same one as x
```

That's because these are the only APIs defined on the class object in C#. To access more interesting APIs I'm going to have to CAST the object into something more specific.
So if, for example I KNOW the object is a ArrayList I can cast it to one:

```
 ArrayList list = (ArrayList) data;
```

Now I can use the API of an arraylist (if the cast worked). So I can do things like:

```
 list.Count; // returns the number of items in the list
 list[x];    // accesses a specific item in the list where x is an integer
```

The cast I showed above is what is known as a "hard" cast. It forces the object into whatever datatype I wanted and (in C#) throws an exception if the cast fails. So typically you only want to use it when you are 100% sure that the object is or SHOULD be that type.

C# also supports what is known as a "soft" cast that returns null if the cast fails.

```
ArrayList list = data as ArrayList;
if(list != null)
{
  // cast worked
}
else
{
  // cast failed
}
```

You'd use the soft cast when you're less sure of the type and want to support multiple types.

Lets say you're the author of the comboBox class. In that case you might want to support different types of .DataSource so you'd probably write the code using soft casts to support many different types:

```
public object DataSource
{
  set
  {
    object newDataSource = value;
    ArrayList list = newDataSource as ArrayList;
    if(list != null)
    {
       // fill combobox with contents of the list
    }
    DataTable table = newDataSource as DataTable;
    if(table != null)
    {
       // fill combobox with contents of the datatable
    }
    // etc
  }
}
```

Hope that helps explain type casting to you and why it is relevant and when to use it! :)